# External-Harddisk drive couldn't run unless in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

This is the strangest thing ever happened to me...

I have an external harddisk drive (ext-HDD), bought around 2 years ago (don't know whether this is an important issue or not).

Here, I have a video file (`.avi`) in my internal harddisk dive (HDD), it worked very well, then I copy it to my ext-HDD, but I couldn't run the file directly from my ext-HDD! I tried to copy it back to my HDD (from the ext-HDD), and now the copy couldn't be run on my HDD too. Remember that I **copy** the file, so the original one was still there.

I tried to go to safe mode (forget to mention, I use Windows 7 Pro), and this is where the strange thing happened, the copied files (both in ext-HDD and HDD) can be run in this safe mode.

So, my question is, what could actually be happened there?

PS: My ext-HDD is Axioo, 250 GB, exFAT...

Edited: Currently I used MacOSX, and the file in the harddisk still can't be run. I haven't tried safe mode for Mac (is there one?), but will try later (if there is)

Comment: Have you tried more than one video player to play the .avi file?

Comment: @GeorgeP.Burdell: yes I've tried it, and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide any details about your error. However it could be that you are having some transfer problems or that your filesystem or even your harddrive is corrupt.
What you could to is try to get hold of a program that calculates a checksum so you can check if your file on your external harddrive is identical to the one on your main disk.

Get a program that can calculate md5 or sha1 checksums.

- Run the checksum program on the .avi file  (primary disk)
- Write down the value you get
- Copy the .avi file to your external harddisk
- Run the checksum program on the .avi file (external disk)
- Write down the value you get and compare it with the previous value. They should match.

If your checksums do not match you got a corruption somewhere. A checksum program will not help you identify the source of your problems but it will help you identify if the files are the same. You can also use a program called VLC to try to play your .avi file just to see if the problem could be with your video player.

Comment: I have checked the checksum, it's perfectly the same... Anyway, I use, and always use VLC

Answer (score 0):

So it copies and plays in safe mode?  1) try disabling your anti-virus temporarily, or 2) make sure your anti-virus is up to date and scan for things...

Also check services.msc to see if there are any odd services that wouldn't be running in safe mode

Comment: will try this...